# Spring Boot @Cachable - how to find out expire datetime at runtime?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching

When using `@Cachable` in Spring, is there any way to find out at runtime if the next method call would be a cache hit or cache miss? Or, at what datetime the cache expires?

The background is, it would be nice to have a scheduled job which refreshes caches just before they expire. Also, this could allow us to find out if caches are expired and show the user a message that the system is now refreshing the caches. "please hold on, we are refreshing your caches for XY" to let the user know what's going on. - Please note we use the `Cacheable` feature to cache method calls which collect data from multiple calls to a 3rd party system which take up to several minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in the Spring Cache abstraction.

As the data collection takes minutes, and the users might need that last value while data is being collected, you can't wait for the cache eviction to collect new data.

One solution would be to add an @Scheduled task that populates the cache calling a method with the @CachePut.

CachedService.java

```
@CachePut(cacheNames="book", key="#isbn")
public Book updateBook(int id, Book book) {
// Left blank
}
```

Config.java

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
public void reportCurrentTime() {
    log.info("refreshing cache");
    ... long data collection ...

    // Call method that has @CachePut
    service.updateBook(bookId, book);

    log.info("cache refreshed");
}
```

The example shows 60000ms (1 minute), it updates the cache every minute. You have to calculate it so it is less time than the Spring Cache expiration time. i.e. (expire time - request time)